# Scan a file for a string of words ignoring extra whitespaces using VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, whitespace

I am searching a file for a string of words. For example "one two three". I have been using:

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(filepath)
For each phrase in phrases
    index = text.IndexOf(phrase, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    If index >= 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

and it worked fine but now I have discovered that some files might contain target phrases with more than one whitespace gaps between words.

for example my code finds

"`one two three`" but fails to find "`one  two  three`"

is there a way I can use regular expressions, or any other technique, to capture the phrase even if distance between words is more than one whitespace?

I know I could use

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(filepath)
For each phrase in phrases
    text=text.Replace("  "," ")
    index = text.IndexOf(phrase, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    If index >= 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

But I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to accomplish that

Comment: You can either hardcode `phrases` to contain a `\s*` between words, where `phrases` are now an array of regex objects. Or, you can construct each phrase as a regex, where you replace `[ ]+` with `\s+`, then use it as a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function to remove any double spaces.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim testString As String = "one two  three   four    five        six"
        Dim excessSpacesGone As String = RemoveExcessSpaces(testString)
        'one two three four five six
        Clipboard.SetText(excessSpacesGone)
        MsgBox(excessSpacesGone)
    End Sub
    Function RemoveExcessSpaces(source As String) As String
        Dim result As String = source
        Do
            result = result.Replace("  ", " "c)
        Loop Until result.IndexOf("  ") = -1
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: the thing is it is not always a double space. I can never predict the number of spaces

Comment: Triple spaces, quadruple, etc... I just named it wrong. It should be named removeExcessSpaces. Test it, it will remove any amount of spaces greater than one.

Answer (score 1):

Comments in the code will explain the code

```
        Dim inputStr As String = "This contains one        Two  three and some     other words" '<--- this be the input from the file
        inputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "\s{2,}", " ") '<--- Replace extra white spaces if any
        Dim searchStr As String = "one two three" '<--- be the string to be searched
        searchStr = Regex.Replace(searchStr, "\s{2,}", " ") '<--- Replace extra white spaces if any
        If UCase(inputStr).Contains(UCase(searchStr)) Then '<--- check if input contains search string
            MsgBox("contains") '<-- display message if it contains
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your phrases into regular expressions with `\s+` between each word, and then check the text for matches against that.  e.g.

```vb
Dim text = "This contains one    Two  three"
Dim phrases = {
    "one two three"
}
' Splits each phrase into words and create the regex from the words.
For each phrase in phrases.Select(Function(p) String.Join("\s+", p.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
    If Regex.IsMatch(text, phrase, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Found!")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Note that this doesn't check for word boundaries at the beginning/end of the phrase, so `"This contains someone  two   threesome"` would also match.  If you don't want that, add `"\s"` at both ends of the regex.

Comment: I get an error:Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type.                        and this part gets highlighted "Function(p) String.Join("\s+", p.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))"

Comment: @ElenaDBA I just copied the code above and pasted it directly into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and it worked without error, so not sure what the issue could be.  In the `Main` method of a new console project (VS2013, .NET 4.5.2) I only had to add an import for `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.  Maybe a typo somewhere?